# ShadowingOuterLocalVariable rubocop error

Tags: ruby, rubocop

here is my code, and here is my error. I think dont need to more descriptions here:

```
#terminal-error    (error on  object  "= ->(object) do "

lib/form_object/base.rb:18:30: W: Lint/ShadowingOuterLocalVariable: Shadowing outer local variable - object.
        need_validation = ->(object) do
```

---

```
def valid?
  valid_attributes = []

  attributes.each do |attribute_name, _attributes|
    attribute_set = self.class.attribute_set[attribute_name]
    object        = self[attribute_name]

    need_validation = ->(object) do
      (object.class < FormObject::Base || attribute_set.options[:validate]) && object.respond_to?(:valid?)
    end

    if need_validation.call(object)
      valid_attributes << object.valid?
    elsif object.is_a?(Array)
      object.each do |nested|
        valid_attributes << nested.valid? if need_validation.call(nested)
      end
    end
  end
  valid_attributes << super

  valid_attributes.all?
end
```

Comment: rename the argument of the lambda, it is the same variable name _object_ that you use elsewhere.

Answer (score 1):

It's a warning from a lint that you run, which detects cases where you shadow (i.e. hide) another local variable, from an outer scope.

You have:

```
object        = self[attribute_name]

need_validation = ->(object) do
  (object.class < FormObject::Base || attribute_set.options[:validate]) && object.respond_to?(:valid?)
end
```

So the first variable `object` could not be referred to inside the lambda, as the argument is also called `object`.

You can remove this warning by simply renaming the parameter of your lambda:

```
need_validation = ->(obj) do
  (obj.class < FormObject::Base || attribute_set.options[:validate]) && obj.respond_to?(:valid?)
end
```